# agolservices.FindRoutes not working (ArcPy)?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-online, route

I am trying to loop through two layers (stops and barriers), and select from each using a common ID. Once the appropriate stops and barriers are selected, I would like to run the Find Routes tool using AGOL's routing service. I am prepared to have the script use credits and I have ensured I have enough, so the issue is not related to that as far as I know.

I am importing the Route module like so:

```
gis = GIS("Pro") # I am logged into my organization through ArcGIS Pro 

route_service = "https://logistics.arcgis.com/arcgis/services;World/Route;"
arcpy.ImportToolbox(route_service)
```

I then loop through everything using the following code:

```
# Create stops layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(start_end_points,"stops_lyr")

## Create bridge barriers
arcpy.analysis.Buffer(bridges, barriers, "10 Meters", "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(barriers,"barriers_lyr")

bridge_list = [55, 37, 12]
for b in bridge_list:
    # Select relevant stops and barriers for routes
    barrier_query = """"ORIG_FID" = {}""".format(b)
    stops_query = """Bridge_OID = '{}'""".format(b)
    arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute("barriers_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", barrier_query)
    arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute("stops_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", stops_query)
    # Run Route tool
    result = arcpy.agolservices.FindRoutes("stops_lyr", "Minutes", "NorthAmerica", Return_to_Start=True,
                                            Polygon_Barriers = "barriers_lyr", Use_Hierarchy=True, Travel_Mode="Custom",                                                    Output_Format="Feature Set")
   

    result.getOutput(1).save(output_routes)
```

The above results in the following error:

RuntimeError: ResultObject: Error in getting output

My credit usage is not going down so I don't think the tool is even running. When I call results.status, I get "4" as a result, and the messages all say that it was a success.